# Verify Captcha function

Tags: php, javascript, captcha

I am having trouble creating a validation code for the captcha I wrote. This is the captcha.php:

```
<?php
  // this part should be saved as captcha.php
  // best usage is to put this file with 5 random TTF font files in a folder named captcha
  // for easy access and simplicity of use
  // Captcha script for GD > 2.0
  /* Few notes about this script
  the width and height are measured in px so adjust according to your desire
  most variables in the variable section control the entire script
  so no editing below them should be needed
  the session variable $_SESSION['tt_pass'] is what holds the pass in the session
  can be changed on line 45
  */
  /********************VARIABLES FOR THIS SCRIPT********************/
  /*********SHOULD BE THE ONLY THING YOU HAVE TO CHANGE*********/
  $pass_length = 5; // passphrase length
  $make_upper = true; // all upper case letters in image? true or false
  $width = 200; $height = 60; // image dimensions
  $font_path = dirname(__FILE__);
  // TTF font @ only change this if you relocate the TTF files!
  $dark_font = true;
  // if you want it easier to read, side effect bots can read it easier as well  true or false
  /********************END VARIABLES FOR SCRIPT********************/
  /*********         EDIT BELOW THIS AT YOUR OWN RISK :)           *********/
  // create a passphrase  ** it is case sensitive!!! **
  session_start();
  $passwd = 'Swatsolutions';
  $i = 0;
  while ($i < $pass_length) {
    $passwd .= chr(rand(97, 122));
    $i++;
  }
  if ($make_upper) {
    $passwd = strtoupper($passwd);
  }
  // store the passphrase
  $_SESSION['tt_pass'] = $passwd;
  // get available fonts
  $fonts = array();
  if ($handle = opendir($font_path)) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
      if (substr(strtolower($file), -4, 4) == '.ttf') {
        $fonts[] = $font_path.'/'.$file;
      }
    }
  }
  if (count($fonts) < 1) {
    die('No Fonts Found!!!');
  }
  // image header
  header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
  // clear the cache
  header("Expires: Fri, 09 Jan 2008 05:00:00 GMT");
  header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s")."GMT");
  header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
  header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
  header("Pragma: no-cache");
  // create image
  $img = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
  // fill background with random shade of pastel
  $bg = imagecolorallocate($img, rand(210, 255), rand(210, 255), rand(210, 255));
  // draw rectangle
  imagefilledrectangle($img, 0, 0, $width, $height, $bg);
  // make the background jaggedy with differnet colored polygons
  $right = rand(10, 30);
  $left = 0;
  while ($left < $width) {
    $poly_points = array(
      $left, 0,
      $right, 0,
      rand($right-25, $right+25), $height, rand($left-15, $left+15), $height);
      $c = imagecolorallocate($img, rand(210, 255), rand(210, 255), rand(210, 255));
      imagefilledpolygon($img, $poly_points, 4, $c);
      $random_amount = rand(10, 30);
      $left += $random_amount;
      $right += $random_amount;
    }
    // base range for lines
    $c_min = rand(150, 185);
    $c_max = rand(195, 280);
    // draw vertical lines
    $left = 0;
    while ($left < $width) {
      $right = $left + rand(3, 7);
      $offset = rand(-3, 3);
      $line_points = array(
        $left, 0,
        $right, 0,
        $right + $offset, $height,
        $left + $offset, $height
      );
      $pc = imagecolorallocate($img, rand($c_min, $c_max),
        rand($c_min, $c_max),
        rand($c_min, $c_max));
      imagefilledpolygon($img, $line_points, 4, $pc);
      $left += rand(20, 60);
    }
    // draw horisontal lines
    $top = 0;
    while ($top < $height) {
      $bottom = $top + rand(1, 4);
      $offset = rand(-6, 6);
      $line_points = array(
        0, $top,
        0, $bottom,
        $width, $bottom + $offset,
        $width, $top + $offset
      );
      $pc = imagecolorallocate($img, rand($c_min, $c_max),
        rand($c_min, $c_max),
        rand($c_min, $c_max));
      imagefilledpolygon($img, $line_points, 4, $pc);
      $top += rand(8, 15);
    }
    // character spacing
    $spacing = $width/(strlen($passwd)+2);
    $x = $spacing;
    // draw each character
    for ($i=0; $i < strlen($passwd); $i++) {
      $letter = $passwd[$i];
      $size = rand($height/3, $height/2);
      $rotation = rand(-30, 30);
      $y = rand($height * .90, $height - $size - 4);
      // random font
      $font = $fonts[array_rand($fonts)];
      // color for letter
      if ($dark_font) {
        $r = rand(0, 200); $g = rand(0, 200); $b = rand(0, 200);
      } else {
        $r = rand(100, 255); $g = rand(100, 255); $b = rand(100, 255);
      }
      // create letter and shadow colors
      $color = imagecolorallocate($img, $r, $g, $b);
      $shadow = imagecolorallocate($img, $r/3, $g/3, $b/3);
      // draw the shadow than letter
      imagettftext($img, $size, $rotation, $x, $y, $shadow, $font, $letter);
      imagettftext($img, $size, $rotation, $x-1, $y-3, $color, $font, $letter);
      // space the letter
      $x += rand($spacing, $spacing * 1.5);
    }
    // clear the memory used to make the captcha image
    imagejpeg($img);
    imagedestroy($img);
  ?>
```

All the function is being processed through the functions page in Wordpress. I am extremely new to Wordpress and I am doing this as a favor for a friend. If someone could help write the code to validate the captcha I would greatly appreciate it. At the link below you can see I have the captcha and the refresh working but with no actual function as it just allows the form to be sent without checking the captcha.

http://swatbeta.brilliantbulb.com/contact/request-info/

Here is the quote.php form I need to the function for can someone tell me what and where to add the code.  I am having information overload and can't seem to the is right for reason.

```
    <?php
    $to = "@gmail.com,@brilliantbulb.com";
    $from = $_POST["email"];
    $subject = "Quote Request";
    $name =  $_POST['name'];
    $phone =  $_POST['phone'];
    $project_description =  $_POST['project_description'];
    $project_timeline =  $_POST['project_timeline'];
    $email = $_POST["email"];




    // validation
    $validationOK=true;
    if (Trim($email)=="") $validationOK=false;
    if (!$validationOK) {
      print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=/?page_id=258\">";
      exit;
    }
    $body = "Please contact the following person to discuss their project outlined    below.\n\nFrom: $name\nEmail: $email\nPhone: $phone\n\nProject Description:\n$project_description\n\nThe following is information concerning the timeline.\n$project_timeline

    ";

    $success = mail($to,$subject,$body,"From: <$email>");

    if ($success){
      print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=/thank-you/\">";
    }
    else{
      print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=/?page_id=258\">";
    }

       ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The captcha needs to be validated on the server side otherwise its simple to bypass.

Inside `quote.php` where the form posts to, add `session_start();` at the beginning of the script and prior to sending the form data to email, use some code similar to the following to validate the captcha:

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['tt_pass']) && $_SESSION['tt_pass'] === $_POST['tt_pass']) {
    // captcha is valid, proceed to send mail
    unset($_SESSION['tt_pass']);  // code valid, cannot be used more than once
} else {
    // captcha code is invalid, redisplay form and show error message
    echo 'The security code entered was incorrect.  ' 
        .'Please <a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">go back</a> and try again.';
    exit;
}
```

If you don't want the comparison to be case-sensitive, pass the session value and the form value through `strtolower()`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ok, so I can't add it to the formcheck() function script?

Comment: Disabling javascript would then mean the check could be bypassed.  Also the only secure way that Javascript could validate the captcha code would be to make an Ajax request to the server verifying the challenge.

Comment: I made an edit and added the code of the quote.php page.  I can't seem to figure out where to add the code you posted above.  I guess I am having an information overload. LOL

Comment: Is that the complete source of quote.php?  I don't see anything in there that actually receives the form data and sends it somewhere.  Are you using some sort of contact form plugin for that or is it not working fully yet?

Comment: No worries.  There isn't much error checking in there, but if you add the captcha check before the line `$success = mail($to,$subject,$body,"From: <$email>");` then it will only send the mail if the captcha is valid.

Comment: ok, that is working but now it is sending them to the wrong thank you page or if the captcha is wrong its not returning them to the form.  Can you help with this.  It is sending email if it correct and not sending them if it is not correct but is just being redirected to the wrong pages. oops spoke too soon, it is still sending the message if the captcha is incorrect, just much slower than if it correct

Comment: If the captcha is invalid then you need to make sure to terminate execution of the script so it doesn't continue running.  You could redirect back to the form but everything they entered would be lost.  You could save the values to the session in the event of error and use that to repopulate the form next time its displayed.

Comment: I must just be on information overload, I am having a hard time visualizing what you recommended.  can you give more specifics please.

Comment: I just edited the code example to show what I mean. You should insert that code right before the line that calls `mail()`.  It's not ideal (the back button) but is a start.

Comment: GREAT Thanks.  Just one final question.  If I wanted to echo the $success portion if the validation is correct how would that piece of the script look?

Answer (score 0):

If your MVC has a session class, that starts the session inside it in the __construct function.

at the top of `captcha.php` put

```
<? php include ("../../library/session.class.php");

try
{
    $session = new Session();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
```

instead of the standard: `session_start();`.